# Accidentally wrote over external hard drive with an img file using dd

Tags: macos, data-recovery

I had two partitions, one "clear" and one encrypted.

Had my iPhoto library.

On the encrypted partition.

I am slightly panicking now.

Any ideas on how to recover my data?

Various relevant outputs;

```
$ diskutil list
(snip)
/dev/disk4
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:     FDisk_partition_scheme                        *1.0 TB     disk4
   1:             Windows_FAT_32 boot                    58.7 MB    disk4s1
   2:                      Linux                         3.2 GB     disk4s2

# diskutil cs list
(nothing pertaining to disk4)
```

Comment: We have a lot of threads covering how to a) recover from an inadvertent dd b) how to do file recovery of OS X partitions from Windows or OS X c) restore a backup. Could you add some details to make your situation different enough from the previous threads and we can certainly re-open this. Just use the edit control under the tags to clarify why the existing threads are not working for you.

Comment: http://apple.stackexchange.com/search?q=dd+recover

Comment: Perfect - and if you have a `diskutil list` and `diskutil cs list` from the drive, that would be reason enough to open this as we'd have some things to explain that I don't see covered here yet.

Comment: @bmike, I updated with the requested info, but it doesn't seem to hold any relevant data. I am going to boot an Ubuntu image now to try my hand at `gparted` as per another suggestion. Wish me luck!

Comment: Well shit, Ubuntu bootable holds `gparted` but misses part of `gpart`, apparently. Which would be fine if it had network drivers for my MBP. Aaanyway, I'll let some commercial software scan overnight and hope it'll get at least my iPhoto libraries. I realized I have one on each partition, so if only one is salvageable I am both happy and sad.