# How do I recover my data/OS after accidentally writing over my main hard drive with an img file using dd?

Tags: macos, hard-drive, startup, data-recovery

I accidentally wrote over main hard drive with an img file using dd.

This thread is the [similar](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/155655/accidentally-wrote-over-external-hard-drive-with-an-img-file-using-dd) but my case is that I accidentally wrote my main hard drive.

I have a late 2013 MBP 13" Retina 256GB SSD 8GB RAM running Yosemite so I don't have a DVD drive. Due to the incident my OS won't boot at all.

I'm kinda worried about my old photos and movies of my fiance stored on my Hard Drive which is not yet backed up on an external drive.

I converted a 900+MB xubuntu.iso to an img and used dd command to write it out to a flash disk, but accidentally type disk1 instead of disk2. I just noticed it after the dd was executed already

```
    # command used in mac terminal
    sudo dd if=/path/to/xubuntu.img of=/dev/rdisk1 bs=1m
```

EDIT: I also tried single user mode but it throws in error because the OS was already overwritten :(

EDIT2: Corrected Laptop Model and added specs

Comment: hi @klanomath I added the command on the question. Thanks

Comment: my mac is using 256 SSD

Comment: sorry it was late 2013 13" mac book pro retina.

Comment: Try using the Target Disk mode (need a second Mac) to recover stuff.

Comment: @Buscar웃 I'll try target disk mode tomorrow in the office. Hoping one of my officemates owns a thunderbolt cable

Answer (score 0):

If I was in the same or similar situation, this is what I'd try...

Using another Mac I'd download Yosemite from the App Store and then create a USB Installer.  Next I'd boot the Mac with the Yosemite USB Installer and install Yosemite to an External USB Drive, preferably a USB 3.0 HDD/SSD or even a large Thumb Drive.  Once the install to the External USB Drive is complete I'd boot the Mac from it and then download and install [Ontrack EasyRecovery](http://www.krollontrack.com/software/free-downloads/) (on the external disk) then shutdown and move the External USB Drive to your MacBook Pro and boot from it. Then run Ontrack EasyRecovery and see what can be recovered.  If the trial shows promising results then purchase the product and recover as much of your User Data that you can.

Comment: I'll try that thx. I will update the thread on what will happen.